# Error converting tensorflow tensor to list of tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to convert a tensor to list of tensors to properly feed it into the embedding layer of my model. Without lists, the layer raises `InvalidArgumentError: indices[2,88] = 9 is not in [0, 9) [Op:ResourceGather]` at runtime but with lists (i.e. `model(list(x))`) i get the correct output.

I'm converting a tf Tensor to list like so:

```py
x = [x[i, :] for i in range(6)]
```

I've tried using `list(x)` but that would result in an `Autograph` error by tensorflow.

The tensor shape is (6,1024) which is loaded via `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`, and i expect to get a list of 6 tensors of length 1024 and get the following error:

```
ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice_1}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=2, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=2, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](args, strided_slice_1/stack, strided_slice_1/stack_1, strided_slice_1/stack_2)' with input shapes: [1,1024], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 0>, input[2] = <2 0>, input[3] = <1 1>.
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: It would seem your tensor does not really have the shape you think. You can also use [`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) to do that same operation.

Comment: @jdehesa thanks for your response. i think it helped but i am now seeing another error that has to do with a Concatenation layer.